# Error "Makefrag-verilator:20: recipe for target" while running "make" in VCS, Emulator Vsim directories

Tags: rocket-chip

I am working on building the Rocket-Chip on my Ubuntu 18.04. I have already built the RISC-V toolchain, RISC-V Tools, Rocket-Tools, Vertilator, Sbt on my machine.

I am following the guidelines demonstrated on https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip

So, I followed the following steps:

1. Changed directory to rocket-chip/emulator
2. run make

Then, every time, I face the same error below (Head to the last line of the running log), given that I face exactly the same error whenever I try to build the VCS, or run the `make verilog` in Vsim directory.

How can I solve this issue, given that I reinstalled the vertilator as explained in [Chisel3 respo on Github](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3).

```
find: ‘/home/user/rocket-chip/api-config-sifive/design/craft/src/main/scala’: No such file or directory
mkdir -p /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/
cd /home/user/rocket-chip && java -Xmx2G -Xss8M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /home/user/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar "runMain freechips.rocketchip.system.Generator /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src freechips.rocketchip.system TestHarness freechips.rocketchip.system DefaultConfig"
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings for project rocket-chip-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/user/rocket-chip/project
[info] Loading settings for project rocketchip from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading settings for project hardfloat from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading settings for project api-config-chipsalliance from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading settings for project chisel from build.sbt ...
Using addons: 
[info] Set current project to rocketchip (in build file:/home/user/rocket-chip/)
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list
[info] Running freechips.rocketchip.system.Generator /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src freechips.rocketchip.system TestHarness freechips.rocketchip.system DefaultConfig
[info] [0.005] Elaborating design...
Interrupt map (2 harts 2 interrupts):
  [1, 2] => dut

<stdout>: Warning (simple_bus_reg): Node /soc/external-interrupts missing or empty reg/ranges property
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    compatible = "freechips,rocketchip-unknown-dev";
    model = "freechips,rocketchip-unknown";
    L13: cpus {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        L6: cpu@0 {
            clock-frequency = <0>;
            compatible = "sifive,rocket0", "riscv";
            d-cache-block-size = <64>;
            d-cache-sets = <64>;
            d-cache-size = <16384>;
            d-tlb-sets = <1>;
            d-tlb-size = <32>;
            device_type = "cpu";
            hardware-exec-breakpoint-count = <1>;
            i-cache-block-size = <64>;
            i-cache-sets = <64>;
            i-cache-size = <16384>;
            i-tlb-sets = <1>;
            i-tlb-size = <32>;
            mmu-type = "riscv,sv39";
            next-level-cache = <&L8>;
            reg = <0x0>;
            riscv,isa = "rv64imafdc";
            riscv,pmpregions = <8>;
            status = "okay";
            timebase-frequency = <1000000>;
            tlb-split;
            L4: interrupt-controller {
                #interrupt-cells = <1>;
                compatible = "riscv,cpu-intc";
                interrupt-controller;
            };
        };
    };
    L8: memory@80000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x80000000 0x10000000>;
    };
    L12: soc {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "freechips,rocketchip-unknown-soc", "simple-bus";
        ranges;
        L2: clint@2000000 {
            compatible = "riscv,clint0";
            interrupts-extended = <&L4 3 &L4 7>;
            reg = <0x2000000 0x10000>;
            reg-names = "control";
        };
        L3: debug-controller@0 {
            compatible = "sifive,debug-013", "riscv,debug-013";
            debug-attach = "dmi";
            interrupts-extended = <&L4 65535>;
            reg = <0x0 0x1000>;
            reg-names = "control";
        };
        L0: error-device@3000 {
            compatible = "sifive,error0";
            reg = <0x3000 0x1000>;
        };
        L7: external-interrupts {
            interrupt-parent = <&L1>;
            interrupts = <1 2>;
        };
        L1: interrupt-controller@c000000 {
            #interrupt-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "riscv,plic0";
            interrupt-controller;
            interrupts-extended = <&L4 11 &L4 9>;
            reg = <0xc000000 0x4000000>;
            reg-names = "control";
            riscv,max-priority = <3>;
            riscv,ndev = <2>;
        };
        L9: mmio-port-axi4@60000000 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "simple-bus";
            ranges = <0x60000000 0x60000000 0x20000000>;
        };
        L10: rom@10000 {
            compatible = "sifive,rom0";
            reg = <0x10000 0x10000>;
            reg-names = "mem";
        };
    };
};

Generated Address Map
           0 -     1000 ARWX  debug-controller@0
        3000 -     4000 ARWX  error-device@3000
       10000 -    20000  R X  rom@10000
     2000000 -  2010000 ARW   clint@2000000
     c000000 - 10000000 ARW   interrupt-controller@c000000
    60000000 - 80000000  RWX  mmio-port-axi4@60000000
    80000000 - 90000000  RWXC memory@80000000

[deprecated] Data.scala:486 (10378 calls): litArg is deprecated: "litArg is deprecated, use litOption or litTo*Option"
[warn] There were 1 deprecated function(s) used. These may stop compiling in a future release - you are encouraged to fix these issues.
[warn] Line numbers for deprecations reported by Chisel may be inaccurate; enable scalac compiler deprecation warnings via either of the following methods:
[warn]   In the sbt interactive console, enter:
[warn]     set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
[warn]   or, in your build.sbt, add the line:
[warn]     scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
[info] [15.855] Done elaborating.
[success] Total time: 21 s, completed Nov 7, 2019, 3:31:59 PM
mkdir -p /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/
java -Xmx2G -Xss8M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -cp "/home/user/rocket-chip/firrtl/utils/bin/firrtl.jar":""/home/user/rocket-chip/target/scala-2.12/classes:/home/user/rocket-chip/chisel3/target/scala-2.12/*"" firrtl.Driver -i /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.fir -o /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.v -X verilog --infer-rw TestHarness --repl-seq-mem -c:TestHarness:-o:/home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.conf -faf /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.anno.json -td /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig/
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: firrtl.Driver is deprecated since 1.2!
Please switch to firrtl.stage.FirrtlMain
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total FIRRTL Compile Time: 60111.0 ms
cd /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src && \
/home/user/rocket-chip/scripts/vlsi_mem_gen /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.conf > /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.behav_srams.v.tmp && \
mv -f /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.behav_srams.v.tmp /home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.behav_srams.v
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
Makefrag-verilator:20: recipe for target '/home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.behav_srams.v' failed
make: *** [/home/user/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.behav_srams.v] Error 127
```

Comment: I am having the same problem after building the emulator and then typing 'rocket-chip/emulator$ make run-asm-tests-debug'

Answer (score 0):

It says that it cannot find Python on the path. It might stem from line-ending convention. Please try to convert the script to Unix line-ending.